# App store on iOS won't show the ratings and the rewievs

Tags: ios

So I had an old Apple account I used before but my brother logged out of it and I could not remember the password and I made a new account. In the old account I could see reviews and ratings of games, and since I made a new account I can't see the ratings and the reviews! All I see are games with empty stars and no reviews.

I made the new account Mongolian because I'am Mongolian the old one I made the region USA. just in CA.

Comment: What iOS version are you using? If you have installed the iOS 9 beta you can't rate apps because it isn't a stable software.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the change of store.
Smaller stores don't have enough reviews to show. Look for a very popular app (Facebook, Snapchat) and you may see reviews, but even then, it may happen that there are not enough reviews for the current version. You can switch to see the reviews for all versions, that may have enough data to be shown.

Or you can switch stores; to do that, go to Settings > iTunes & App Store > Apple ID, enter your password, and tap on Country / Region to Chang your store back to the U.S.

If you have iTunes Match or Apple Music subscriptions running, you'll have to cancel them first.

Comment: thanks it works but now i cant install games it says pls switch back to mongolian store to purchase... so does that mean im stuck with this mongolian store that doesnt even shop ratings and stuff?

Comment: If your credit card is from there, yes. Otherwise I don't know why it is asking you to switch back.